How to remove space in between columns in tabular environment with two tables?
I'm not able to remove the space in the table on the right in the below example:
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
%
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs}
%\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs, counter}
\newtheorem{prop}{proposition}
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt} % for a less cramped "look"
\newcommand\mc[7]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\caption{Timetable and distance matrix}
\label{tab:example_7}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Timetable}\\
\toprule
u & $t_i$  & $l_i$ & $s_i$\\ \midrule
0 & 0.0  & $90 $  & 0.0 \\
7 & 8.0& 1.15   & 1.0  \\
5 & 8.5& 8.75   & 7.0  \\
N & 0.0& $90 $  & 0.0  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Distance Matrix}\\
\toprule
u & 0 & 7 & 5 & Y \\ \midrule
0 & 0 & 7 & 8 & 0 \\
7 & 1 & 0 & 5 & 1   \\
5 & 8 & 2 & 0 & 8   \\
N & 0 & 7 & 8 & 0   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

I've seen a few examples e.g. Remove extra space between \pm columns in tabular environment?, but they are for different environments.  Can someone help me understand what I'm missing?  Thanks.

You want \multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{...} in the first table and \multicolumn{5}{@{}c@{}}{...} in the second one.
Rather than using \extrarowheight, I'd increase the intercolumn space for the particular tables.
Center alignment seems more appropriate, but it's a question of taste.
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{Timetable and distance matrix}
\label{tab:example_7}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}

\begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
\multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{Timetable}\\
\toprule
u & $t_i$  & $l_i$ & $s_i$ \\
\midrule
0 & 0.0 &  90  & 0.0 \\
7 & 8.0 & 1.15 & 1.0 \\
5 & 8.5 & 8.75 & 7.0 \\
N & 0.0 &  90  & 0.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\qquad
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
\multicolumn{5}{@{}c@{}}{Distance Matrix}\\
\toprule
u & 0 & 7 & 5 & Y \\
\midrule
0 & 0 & 7 & 8 & 0 \\
7 & 1 & 0 & 5 & 1 \\
5 & 8 & 2 & 0 & 8 \\
N & 0 & 7 & 8 & 0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}


Important aside.
Your definition of \mc has a bad typo: it should not have [7], but [1].

The llncs document class sets an absurdly small value of just 1.4pt for the value of \tabcolsep; that's the parameter that governs the amount of intercolumn whitespace in tabular-like environment. In most other document classes, the default value of \tabcolsep is 6pt. My main suggestion is that you set a value of 5pt (or larger) for \tabcolsep.
Do note that the first argument of the \multicolumn directives shouldn't be 3 but, rather, 4 and 5, respectively. Why? You want the headers to span all columns, don't you? And, the second argument shouldn't be c but, rather, @{}c@{}, since you presumably don't want whitespace padding on either side.
Finally, since you're using the line-drawing macros of the booktabs package, there's no need to change the default value of \extrarowheight.

\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Timetable and distance matrix}
\label{tab:example_7}
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt} % default: 1.4pt [!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}llll @{}}
\multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{Timetable}\\
\toprule
u & $t_i$ & $l_i$ & $s_i$ \\ \midrule
0 & 0.0  & $90 $  & 0.0   \\
7 & 8.0  & 1.15   & 1.0   \\
5 & 8.5  & 8.75   & 7.0   \\
N & 0.0  & $90 $  & 0.0   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{@{} lllll @{}}
\multicolumn{5}{@{}c@{}}{Distance matrix}\\
\toprule
u & 0 & 7 & 5 & Y \\ \midrule
0 & 0 & 7 & 8 & 0 \\
7 & 1 & 0 & 5 & 1 \\
5 & 8 & 2 & 0 & 8 \\
N & 0 & 7 & 8 & 0 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}

